# Why do I need the extra connection values in mysql connection in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm having an issue with getting my dag to run consistently. At one point when I deployed my dag it ran without an issue. [Dag success and failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1OoX.png). Then after a couple of days it stopped running successfully (Please reference image).

In order to get the dag recognized in `Airflow` I had to edit my MySQL connection in the "extra" column in connections like so:
`{"rewriteBatchedStatements": true, "useServerPrepStmts": false, "charset": "utf8", "cursor": "dictcursor"}`
This made my connection updated to look like so:
[Current Mysql Connection in Airflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPFQg.png). Why is this required? The docs have it as optional.

The code itself has not changed. I did notice that once I updated my connection my dags were no longer broken and I could see them in `Airflow`. However, whenever I run them now, I get the following error:

```
 File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 691, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 686, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 574, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: '__extra__' is an invalid keyword argument for connect()
```

If I take remove the `dictcursor` from the extra column my dags are broken.
[Broken dags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpVQX.png)

Could I please get some insight as to what is going on and what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This might work, try changing the boolean true & false to string. Like,

```
{
    "rewriteBatchedStatements": "true",
    "useServerPrepStmts": "false",
    "charset": "utf8",
    "cursor": "dictcursor"
}
```

Need to understand extra is necessary here at first place, consider editing to why its required?

Comment: Hey, I tried this and it still gave the same error. I have also updated the question like you suggested. That actually make more sense.